# Why doesn't Git recognize my .gitignore exclusions?

Tags: git

I'm pretty new to Git and trying to understand how it works and why.  I have a web project that I'm working on and I have a `.gitignore` file that has the following line:

```
www/*
```

Now, I need to add just the www folder to my repo, so I've added just an empty `.gitignore` file to it and updated my main `.gitignore` file like so:

```
!www/.gitignore
www/*
```

Except, now when I do `git status`, nothing comes up as needed to be added.  In order to add it to the staging, I have to do `git add www/.gitignore -f`.

Why doesn't Git just recognize the exclusion automatically and add the file for me when I do `git add *`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order matters. Both rules match the same file, so the later one wins, and the file is ignored. Your earlier `!` is overridden by your second rule.

You need to put the exclusion second:

```
www/*
!www/.gitignore
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing anything about the `www` directory from your root `.gitignore`, then make the contents of `www/.gitignore`:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

This is how my repo is set up currently and I've had no issues.

Comment: That's a bandaid solution that tries to side-step the problem rather than understanding and fixing it.

Comment: This is true, however I personally think its a more logical to have separate `.gitignore`s for big projects rather than one large, cluttered root `.gitignore`. I've +1'd yours for actually debugging the issue though.

Comment: The problem is that, without understanding the issue, you're likely to encounter the same problem later down the line inside `www/.gitignore`.